# flask.jsonify returns array with square brackets instead of curly brackets

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-restful, jsonify

I am using flask and jsonify for the first time and i am stuck at a small problem. My json output is returning an array format with square brackets instead of the json object with curly brackets.

Can someone pls point me in the right direction?

My function takes a text and using spacy breaks it down into tokens and details about the tokens.

my code is-

```
@app.route('/api/<string:mytext>',methods=['GET'])
def myfunc(mytext):

    docx = nlp(mytext.strip())
    allData = ['Token:{},Tag:{},POS:{}'.format(token.text,token.tag_,token.pos_) for token in docx ]
    
    return jsonify(allData)
```

It returns the data as

```
[
  "Token:\",Tag:``,POS:PUNCT", 
  "Token:test,Tag:VB,POS:VERB", 
  "Token:this,Tag:DT,POS:DET", 
]
```

I want the return JSON to be the standard json response with curly brackets so my c# app can deserialise it properly.

Any help is appreciated.thanks

Comment: Your `allData` variable is a list with 3 Strings, not objects containing 3 entries. Consider creating your `allData` list differently so that it has 3 objects with 3 entries each.

Comment: thanks Septem151, can u sort of share or point in the direction to achieve that. sorry i am not well versed in python. just creating this api to access thru my c# app which is where i code mostly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your list comprehension to create a Python `dict`/curly brackets. It'll still need to be created as a `list`/Array/square brackets as your key names are the same for each line/entity.

```
allData = [{'Token': token.text, 'Tag': token.tag_, 'POS': token.pos_} for token in docx]
```